# How to dynamically select multiple options in multiple select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search form. The search is run against a list of documents - the names of which are populated into a multiple select menu. The user selects the appropriate documents and then performs the search against them.

When the form is submitted, the list of documents that they ran their search against is stored in localStorage as a space-delimited string of option values extracted from the  element values that were selected when they submitted the form.

If the user then desires to perform another search using the exact same documents selected, they ideally should have the option to check a checkbox, and an attached event listener calls localStorage to retrieve the values from the last search.

The stored values are compared to the new multiple select menu option values, and if any option values in the select menu match the stored values, they should be selected.

But it doesn't seem to be working the way I had hoped. It may have something to do with properties vs. attributes, per the jQuery 1.6 update, but even when I use:

```
element.prop('selected', 'selected');
```

or

```
element.removeProp('selected');
```

...the select menu is not updating accordingly. I've been working on this for days, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a bit more code.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE] of your code, which shows the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: How are you defining/creating your "multi select menu"?

Comment: Yes sir, I apologize for the incomplete example. I'm short on time, and the actual code is huge, so trying to extract a minimal, complete, and verifiable example was a tall order in and of itself. I think I got what I needed below from Kristiyan, so I will proceed with that. Thank you for the consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .prop('selected',true).attr('selected',true)
I've created an example for you here:  http://tpcg.io/pPA2nF

After that just change to false and it should work.

Comment: This actually worked on one of the four select menus, so I think you've got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass array of values to jQuery like that:

```
jQuery("#select").val([12,31,42]);
```